# Code when you can't add a comment to a page due to comments closed?

Tags: http-status-codes

I have a web-service that allows a client to add comments to a page, but only as long as the comments section is open. Once the comments section is closed, no further comments are allowed.

In this case, if the server receives a call to add a comment, what status code should it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a security use case. I would return HTTP 403 Forbidden. IE: You are forbidden from adding comments to a closed section.

Comment: How about: 405 Method Not Allowed?

Comment: Check the standards, 405: "method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI". Meaning this resource doesn't expose certain methods (POST, PUT, GET, etc).